# List Assignment Out of Range - Python

Tags: python

I understand that the list assignment doesn't work because it's an empty list, but I don't know how to fix this particular problem. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. The error that is received is `new_list[insert_position] = value` list assignment index out of range. Everything works except the part in the major else part. Note - this specific task asks that I do not use string/list methods apart from `append()`

```
def insert_value(my_list, value, insert_position):
    new_list = []
    if insert_position <= 0:
        new_list.append(value)
        for i in my_list:
            new_list.append(i)
    elif insert_position >= length(my_list):
        for i in my_list:
            new_list.append(i)
        new_list.append(value)
    else:
        index = []
        for i in range(length(new_list)):
            if i != insert_position:
                index.append(i)
        new_list[insert_position] = value
        for i in index:
            if i < insert_position:
                new_list[i] = my_list[i]
            else:
                new_list[i] = my_list[i - 1]

    return new_list

print("\ninsert_value Test")
str_list3 = ['one','three','four', 'five', 'six']
new_list = list_function.insert_value(str_list3, 'two', 1)
```

Comment: This function seems overly complicated... is it just suppose to return a *new list* with a value inserted at a given position?

Comment: The error is arising in your `elif` block. If someone calls the function with an `insert_position` greater than the length of your list, then the error will get thrown there. Handling this scenario, where the user inputs a value greater than the length of the list should help.

Comment: how can it work when you use `length()`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga yes, correct.

Comment: Any reason you can't just do `my_list[:insert_position] + [value] + my_list[insert_position:]`?

Comment: @BallpointBen it's a solution but an inefficient one. You can do it in a single traversal.

Comment: @BallpointBen OP is supposed to `append` only to create the new list. I would assume that slicing isn’t an option.

Comment: Yes, it will have the same time complexity, but the *constant factors* will be about double. If you can do something in one traversal easily, why do it in over 2? Each time you `+` two lists, it traverses each item.

Comment: @poke  correct, I cannot take advantage of slicing.

Answer (score 2):

```
new_list[insert_position] = value
```

At the time you are doing this, `new_list` is still empty, so you cannot assign at a (random) index. If your instructions say that you should only use `append`, then you should do exactly that.

This should be your strategy for solving that third case:

1. Assuming the length of the original list is `n`, the new length of the list will be `n + 1` since you are inserting one element.
2. So loop over all those indexes of the *new* list (`0..n+1`).
3. As long as the current index is still below the index you want to insert at, just append the item from the original list.
4. If you hit the index to insert at, append the new item.
5. For all remaining items of the original list, just append them. Note that your index has advanced by one compared to your original list.

You can also just iterate using the current index of the original list, then you do not need to adjust the index for the remaining items.

---

Bonus points: If you do it correctly, you no longer need to handle the cases `insert_position == 0` and `insert_position == len(my_list)` explicitly.

Comment: I'm assuming in my current code, based on what you've typed out for me, that I just need to add in "new_list.append(value)" in the if statement at the end, correct?

Comment: You don't really even need to split this into three cases, you can you the same core code. Just check if position < 0: position = 0, then at the end, check if position > len(my_list) and append if it is...

Comment: @riyalaise123 No, in your code, you’re using indexed assignment which will all fail since the list is empty. You cannot use `new_list[i] = …` at all, so you will have to modify those parts. And you do not need that `index` list.

Comment: Missed the "bonus points" part, but I upvoted because this is a good answer to a hw question - not giving it away but still explaining how it is wrong.

Comment: @poke Apologises. I am quite stuck on a solution then if it doesn't involving using the index list.

Comment: @riyalaise123 Try to follow the instructions from my answer, without focusing too much on your attempt.

Comment: @poke so far this is what I have
        for i in range(length(new_list)):
            if i < insert_position:
                new_list[i] = my_list[i]
            elif i == insert_position:
                new_list[i] = value

but I still can't get it to really work. I'm sorry if I'm missing something.

Comment: @riyalaise123 `new_list` doesn’t have any items yet, so it doesn’t have a length you could iterate over. And as I said, you can only append to the list since it’s empty, so index assignements don’t work.

Comment: @poke I'm pretty sure I have the correct code now, I just can't figure out how to successfully do Step 4. Can't figure out how to append the new item in its correct position.

Comment: @poke I know you've helped a lot, and I am grateful because I'm even closer than I was before with a better understanding, but if you could guide me slightly more in how this part of the code is meant to be added I will be very grateful.

Comment: You can only ever append to the end of the list (that is what append does). So you only have to figure out which element to append. For items before the target index, this is the index `i`. For items after the index, this would be `i - 1`.

Answer (score 0):

```
elif insert_position >= length(my_list):
```

Change this to:

```
elif insert_position > length(my_list)-1:
```

If your list has 4 items, the length is 4, the last index is 3. So you need to check the index isn't greater than length-1.

Comment: Thank you, I fixed this. Still have my original issue though.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you checked the length of my_list and insert values to `new_list`, the new list is empty but you insert a value to index 1. What you can do is deep copy `my_list` and modify the new list

```
import copy
```

and then replace `new_list=[]` with `new_list = copy.deepcopy(my_list)`

then the new_list result would be

```
['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five']
```

Comment: I doubt if they are allowed to use the `copy` module if they can't use list methods.... Anyway, you don't need a deep copy...

Comment: OP is only supposed to use `list.append`.